# Protecting questions in beta SEs

Tags: support, protected-questions

Normally the privilege of protecting questions comes at 15000 points, but in the econ.SE, [it says you only need 3500](//economics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions):

> [image]

The problem is I cannot seem to be able to find the tool for protecting eligible questions. Where can I find it, or do I still need 15000 points despite what the help section for our beta says?

Comment: Did you note the additional criteria for age and at least one answer by < 10 rep user on http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions? If that's met you get a "protect" option under the Q.

Comment: I missed the at least one answer part. Thank you!

Comment: @rene done and done.